# Angular Material - Missing classes (ex: md-2-line)

Tags: css, angular-material

I am trying to use the md-list

```
<md-list-item class="md-2-line">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="communication:phone"></md-icon>
        <div class="md-list-item-text">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </md-list-item>
```

But I only get normal font and when I do a search in my code for all those classes, I can not find them (for example md-2-line is nowhere to be seen).

I did a bower install angular-material so I am assuming that in the components->list->js->list.css I should see these classes like in the scss on github.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you take the code from the actual examples, but I think they are about the 0.9.0-RC2 version.
When you install from bower you get the 0.8.3 as the latest available.
In the changelog of the 0.9.0-rc1 and the 0.9.0-rc2 you can see some breaking changes in the md-list directive.

I didn't tested by myself, but hope it helps to solve your issue, try adding the following classes to your styles:

```
md-list-item.md-2-line, md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-no-style, md-list-item.md-3-line, md-list-item.md-3-line > .md-no-style {
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start; }
  md-list-item.md-2-line .md-list-item-text, md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text, md-list-item.md-3-line .md-list-item-text, md-list-item.md-3-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    padding: 16px 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; }
    md-list-item.md-2-line .md-list-item-text.md-offset, md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text.md-offset, md-list-item.md-3-line .md-list-item-text.md-offset, md-list-item.md-3-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text.md-offset {
      margin-left: 56px; }
    md-list-item.md-2-line .md-list-item-text h3, md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text h3, md-list-item.md-3-line .md-list-item-text h3, md-list-item.md-3-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text h3 {
      margin: 0 0 6px 0;
      line-height: 0.75em; }
    md-list-item.md-2-line .md-list-item-text h4, md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text h4, md-list-item.md-3-line .md-list-item-text h4, md-list-item.md-3-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text h4 {
      font-weight: 400;
      margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
      line-height: 0.75em; }
    md-list-item.md-2-line .md-list-item-text p, md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text p, md-list-item.md-3-line .md-list-item-text p, md-list-item.md-3-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text p {
      margin: 0 0 0px 0;
      line-height: 1.6em; }

md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-avatar:first-child, md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-no-style > .md-avatar:first-child {
  margin-top: 12px; }
md-list-item.md-2-line > md-icon:first-child, md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-no-style > md-icon:first-child {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
      -ms-flex-item-align: center;
          align-self: center; }
md-list-item.md-2-line .md-list-item-text, md-list-item.md-2-line > .md-no-style .md-list-item-text {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  padding-top: 19px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`md-list-item`'s css classes `md-2-line` `md-3-line` belongs to 0.9.0  -ver. At first I have also the similar problem after I update latest -ver evrything worked as expected.